# How to select an random index from randomly selected object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, random

I want to select a random index from an array object, this object contains two keys author and images array.. I can select a random index from array object but how would i also select a random index from images array based on the random selected array object index?

```
    let resourcesObject = [
      {
        "author" : "photographer1",
        "images1": ['cat1','cat2','cat3'] 

      },
      {
        "author" : "photographer2",
        "images2": ['dog1', 'dog2', 'dog3', 'dog4'] 

      }

      ];

    console.log(resourcesObject[Math.floor(Math.random() * resourcesObject.length)]); // gives me a random object as expected { author: 'photographer2',images2: [ 'dog1', 'dog2', 'dog3', 'dog4' ] }, //but i also want to select a random index from the images2 how would i do that?
```

Comment: Save resourcesObject[Math.floor(Math.random() * resourcesObject.length)] on variable and use that variable to find random indax as well

Comment: like this? `console.log(savedIndex.images1[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]);` but if it's the other object that contains images2 it will be an error or i'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps!
It works good for me:

```
var resourcesObject = [
        {
            "author" : "photographer1",
            "images1": ['cat1','cat2','cat3']

        },
        {
            "author" : "photographer2",
            "images2": ['dog1', 'dog2', 'dog3', 'dog4']

        }
    ];


    function randomize(n){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
    }

    var n = resourcesObject.length;
    var randomIndex = randomize(n);
    var selectedObj = resourcesObject[randomIndex]['images' + (randomIndex + 1)];
    var randomImg = selectedObj[(Math.floor(Math.random() * selectedObj.length))];

    console.log(randomImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives random Object

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Looping through arrays inside arrays.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var myObj;
myObj = [
  {
    "author" : "photographer1",
    "images1": ['cat1','cat2','cat3'] 

  },
  {
    "author" : "photographer2",
    "images2": ['dog1', 'dog2', 'dog3', 'dog4'] 

  }

  ]


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 0  ];

 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example to extract functionality into a little function to choose the index based on the length of an array

```
function getRandomIndex( array ) {
  return parseInt( Math.random() * array.length );
}
```

Which you could then use as:

```
let resourcesObject = [
  {
    "author" : "photographer1",
    "images1": ['cat1','cat2','cat3'] 

  },
  {
    "author" : "photographer2",
    "images2": ['dog1', 'dog2', 'dog3', 'dog4'] 

  }
];

let resourceIndex = getRandomIndex( resourcesObject );
// is images part of the index, or is there a reason to have images1 or images2
let imageProp = 'images' + (resourceIndex + 1);
let imageIndex = getRandomIndex( resourcesObject[resourceIndex][imageProp] );

let image = resourcesObject[resourceIndex][imageProp][imageIndex];
```

In case the images are either in images1 or in images2 you could make it yourself a bit easier by doing

```
let imageArray = resourcesObject[resourceIndex].images1 || resourcesObject[resourceIndex].images2;
```

which would pick either of the 2, and then you could work with the `imageArray` instead

Answer (score 0):

```js
let resourcesObject = [
      {
        "author" : "photographer1",
        "images1": ['cat1','cat2','cat3'] 

      },
      {
        "author" : "photographer2",
        "images2": ['dog1', 'dog2', 'dog3', 'dog4'] 

      },
        {
        "author" : "photographer3",
        "images3": ['rat1', 'rat2', 'rat3', 'rat4'] 

      },
        {
        "author" : "photographer4",
        "images4": ['bat1', 'bat2', 'bat3', 'bat4'] 

      }

      ];

    let obj=resourcesObject[Math.floor(Math.random() * resourcesObject.length)];
    let value=Object.keys(obj)[1];
     console.log(obj[value][Math.floor(Math.random() * obj[value].length)])
```